# Coverting a Byte array to CGImage

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a grayscale values of an image in an unsigned char array and I want to convert that into `CGImage` so that I can use it to display it in iOS via `UIImage`. Each value of unsigned char array is pixel value of grayscale image. I am using the following code but image is not displayed.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rectange4obs1pro" ofType:@"pgm"];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
/////////////// read file ///////////
FILE *file = fopen([filename UTF8String], "rb");
if (file == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"File Not Found");
    return;
}
char name[20], secondline[10];
int w=0, h=0, colors=0;
fscanf(file, "%s", name);
fscanf(file, "%s", secondline);
fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &w, &h, &colors);
printf("%d %d\n", w, h);
unsigned char * imagedata = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*w*h);
fseek(file, 1, SEEK_CUR);
int i=0;
while (!feof(file)) {
    imagedata[i] = getc(file);
    i++;
}
////////////////// end read file /////////////

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace= CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGContextRef bitmapContext=CGBitmapContextCreate(imagedata, w, h, 8, w, colorSpace,  kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
CFRelease(colorSpace);
free(imagedata);
CGImageRef cgImage=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);

UIImage * newimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
[imageview setImage:newimage];
}
```

The message I am getting on terminal is:

> CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer
>   bits/component; 16 bits/pixel; 1-component color space;
>   kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast; 100 bytes/row. Jan 31 15:25:50
>   sumits-mbp.bsb.igloonet check_visibility_image[4210] :
>   CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
>   error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
>   context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
>   system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: Do you have more details on the image format the data represents? From the error message it is clear that the image data you provide doesn't fit to the parameters you use to create the BitmapContext. For example `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast` probably is `kCGImageAlphaNone` for normal grayscale images.

Comment: If it works I might post the comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working now, I got the issue.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"10CamsHGallery" ofType:@"pgm"];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
/////////////// read file ///////////
FILE *file = fopen([filename UTF8String], "rb");
if (file == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"File Not Found");
    return;
}
char name[20], secondline[10];
int w=0, h=0, colors=0;
fscanf(file, "%s", name);
fscanf(file, "%s", secondline);
fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &w, &h, &colors);
//printf("%d %d\n", w, h);
unsigned char * imagedata = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*w*h);
fseek(file, 1, SEEK_CUR);
int i=0;
while (!feof(file)) {
    int val = getc(file);
    imagedata[i] = val;
    i++;
}
////////////////// end read file /////////////

CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CFDataRef rgbData = CFDataCreate(NULL, imagedata, w * h);
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(rgbData);
CGImageRef rgbImageRef = CGImageCreate(w, h, 8, 8, w , colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CFRelease(rgbData);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
UIImage * newimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:rgbImageRef];
imageview.frame = CGRectMake(imageview.frame.origin.x,imageview.frame.origin.y, w, h);
[imageview setImage:newimage];
CGImageRelease(rgbImageRef);
```

}